# I want to create a checkbox when button is clicked

Tags: java, android

I want to make it so that every time someone types something in the `editText` and clicks the button, the text comes up. It does it in my code, but I also want to add a checkbox next to it. How can I add the checkbox every time the button is pressed?

This is how it looks in the emulator right now after I typed test in the editText:

https://gyazo.com/6b9a050976ecd2c4b509220263bbdce1

The second problem is: when I write a second todo, it overwrites the last one so right now I can only have 1 todo. Why?

Code:

```
final TextView textViewPrint;    
Button btn_print;           
final EditText editTextType;    
textViewPrint = findViewById(R.id.print_text);           
btn_print = findViewById(R.id.button_add);             
editTextType = findViewById(R.id.test_textEdit);

btn_print.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                textViewPrint.setText(editTextType.getText().toString()) ; 
                editTextType.setText("");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add to your layout programmatically after it has been inflated. Add an id to your LinearLayout:

```
android:id ="@+id/layout"
```

Then in OnCreate (after your existing code), get a reference to it and add controls as you wish. And add these lines in OnCreate, For example:

```
LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
int lHeight = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
int lWidth = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
l.addView(cb, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(lHeight, lWidth));
setContentView(l);
```

Comment: Hello I use constraintLayout instead of linearlayout so i switched out all of the linear layout with constraintLayout and got this error:  The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first. Dosen't it work with constraintLayout I looked up the error on stack overflow and someone said this 

Just for someone who gets same error: Make sure you add correct element. Lets say you have to add LinearLayout but you add TextView. So fix it

Answer (score 0):

#### First You need add to LinearLayout layout

```
LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
btn_print.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
                LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(
                      LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                cb.setLayoutParams(lparams);
                l.addView(cb);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Hello I use constraintLayout instead of linearlayout so i switched out all of the linear layout with constraintLayout and got this error:  The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first. Dosen't it work with constraintLayout I looked up the error on stack overflow and someone said this 

Just for someone who gets same error: Make sure you add correct element. Lets say you have to add LinearLayout but you add TextView. So fix it

Comment: Use LinearLayout instead of constraintLayout